# comparing given word with a string in an array

Tags: c, arrays, c-strings

I'm trying to find a way to compare a given word to an array of strings and eventually insert the "biggest" word (according to ASCII table) into a new array.

My question is; can I refer to a string inside the array as a regular location?
for example

```
char arr[]={"hello", "world"};
```

can I refer to "hello" as `arr[0]` and "world" as `arr[1]`?

Comment: It has to be `char *arr[] = {"hello, "world"};` Then you may refer to the strings as `arr[0]` and `arr[1]`.

Comment: great, you helped me a lot! thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that. Indeed, when you try compiling your code you receive this king of error

```
test.c:2:22: error: excess elements in char array initializer
    2 | char arr[]={"hello", "world"};
      |                      ^~~~~~~
test.c:2:22: note: (near initialization for ‘arr’)
```

It means you have declared an array of 1 block, bit that you are trying to initialize it with more than 1 block (2 in that case). 
You need to change your declaration by :

```
char *arr[] = {"hello", "world");
```

and everything should be fine !